# Keras error in Dense layer, expected 4 dimensions got array with shape (1024,2)

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I'm attempting to train a model of 3 layer Dense Neural Network using Keras with a GPU enabled Tensorflow backend.

The dataset I have is 4 million 20x40px images that I placed in directories with the name of the category they belong to.

Because of the large amount of data I can't just load it all into RAM and feed it to my model so I thought using [Keras's ImageDataGenerator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/), specifically the function flow_from_directory() would do the trick. This yields a tuple of (x, y) where x is the numpy array of the image and y is the label of the image.

I expected the model to know to access the numpy array to be given as input for my model so I setup my input shape to be: (None,20,40,3) where None is the batch size, 20 and 40 are size of the image and 3 are the number of channels in the image. This does not work however as when I try to train my model I keep getting the error:
**ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1024, 2)**

I know the cause is that it is getting the tuple from flow_from_directoy and I guess I could change the input shape to match, however, I fear that this would render my model useless as I will be using images to make predictions not a pre-categorized tuple. So my question is, how can I get flow_from_directory to feed the image to my model and only use the tuple to validate it's training? Am I misunderstanding something here?

For reference, here is my code:

```python
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import *
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard

# Prepare the Image Data Generator.
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '/path/to/train_data/',
    target_size=(20, 40),
    batch_size=1024,
)

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '/path/to/test_data/',
    target_size=(20, 40),
    batch_size=1024,
)

# Define input tensor.
input_t = Input(shape=(20,40,3))

# Now create the layers and pass the input tensor to it.
hidden_1 = Dense(units=32, activation='relu')(input_t)
hidden_2 = Dense(units=16)(hidden_1)
prediction = Dense(units=1)(hidden_2)

# Now put it all together and create the model.
model = Model(inputs=input_t, outputs=prediction)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Prepare Tensorboard callback and start training.
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir='./graph', histogram_freq=0, write_graph=True, write_images=True)
print(test_generator)
model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=2000,
    epochs=100,
    validation_data=test_generator,
    validation_steps=800,
    callbacks=[tensorboard]
)

# Save trained model.
model.save('trained_model.h5')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input shape is wrong for Dense layers.

Dense layers expect inputs in the shape (None,length).

You'll either need to reshape your inputs so that they become vectors:

```
imageBatch=imageBatch.reshape((imageBatch.shape[0],20*40*3))
```

Or use convolutional layers, that expect that type of input shape (None,nRows,nCols,nChannels) like in **tensorflow**.

Comment: In my case I added a Flatten() layer in front of the Dense layer and that fixed the problem.